# Sort - List files by their latest modified date but only show files with the same latest day

Tags: find, ls, sort

Let's say I want to find files base from the last given modified days and sort list base from the latest modified date.

**E.g.**

```
find /path/to/files -mtime -15 | xargs -d '\n' -r ls -t
```

**Output:** note: I will just indicate the modified date in the filename to show their modified date

```
/path/to/file_EEE_2018Apr01.dat
/path/to/file_DDD_2018Apr01.dat
/path/to/file_CCC_2018Apr01.dat
/path/to/file_AAA_2018Mar28.dat
/path/to/file_BBB_2018Mar26.dat
```

Then I want to get the those files with the latest modified date but the same day

**E.g. Final output:** This is taken from the result of the first output.

```
/path/to/file_EEE_2018Apr01.dat
/path/to/file_DDD_2018Apr01.dat
/path/to/file_CCC_2018Apr01.dat
```

Comment: The Best would ne to explain what you want to do clearly because i have read your question 3 times ans Im still unsure about what you want. Also as the question on the site should not be opinion base the phrasing : what is the Best way is rarely the Best way to ask here ;-)

Comment: @Kiwy, ok I'll remove it

Comment: If you would have several files from March 26th should they show up in the result as well? If there is only one file modified on the most recent days but several files modified on a past day (e.g. March 28th in your sample) what should get shown?

Comment: @patrix only show the files with the same latest day from the output of `find /path/to/files -mtime -15 | xargs -d '\n' -r ls -t`

Answer (score 3):

This will do it:

```
FIND_PATH='/path/to/files'; find "$FIND_PATH" -newermt $(find "$FIND_PATH" -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n' | sort | tail -1)
```

The "inner" `find` will print all modification dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format and print only the newest (`| sort | tail -1`).

The "outer" `find` will only find files with this date.